# Incompatibility of complexity and polyglossia

Tags: polyglossia, complexity

The following simple MWE, generates an error:

```
\documentclass{book}

\usepackage{complexity}
\usepackage{polyglossia}
  \setdefaultlanguage[variant=american]{english}

\begin{document}
Test!
\end{document}
```

literally:

```
! LaTeX Error: Command \lang already defined.
               Or name \end... illegal, see p.192 of the manual.
```

Is this something that can be dealt with at user level?

Comment: I wouldn't use this complexity package. It defines imho much to many commands and so can clash easy with other packages.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `complexity` package defines `\lang` to typeset “language” names such as `\CVP` (Circuit Value Problem) and `\SAT` (Satisfiability). I'm not sure whether classifying these as “languages” is sound. Anyway, it's definitely not possible to change the name.

On the other hand, `polyglossia` defines a `lang` environment by

```
\newenvironment{lang}[2][]{%
  \begin{otherlanguage}[#1]{#2}%
}{%
  \end{otherlanguage}
}%
```

which is basically a shorthand for `otherlanguage`.

You need to make a choice:

1. not using `complexity`; or
2. avoiding the `lang` environment in favor of `otherlanguage`.

If you pursue the latter strategy, do

```
\documentclass{book}

\usepackage{polyglossia}
% undefine the lang environment
\let\lang\relax\let\endlang\relax

\usepackage{complexity}

\setdefaultlanguage[variant=american]{english}

\begin{document}

Test!

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1):

The `complexity` package defined the `\lang` macro.

The `polyglossia` package defined the `lang` environment (i.e. `\lang` and `\endlang` macros).

You can rename the `lang` environment into `polyglossialang` before loading the `complexity` package.

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{polyglossia}
% rename 'lang' environment to 'polyglossialang'
\let\polyglossialang\lang
\let\endpolyglossialang\endlang
\let\lang\relax
%
\usepackage{complexity}
\setmainlanguage{english}
\setotherlanguage{french}
\begin{document}
Test!
\begin{polyglossialang}{french}
Test!
\end{polyglossialang}
\end{document}
```